# Send Incoming Email to Multiple Mailboxes

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, email-server, windows-sbs

I have a bit of an interesting email situation I'm trying to set up for a small business, that is probably far from normal, but I'm hoping someone can send me along the right path.

Suppose I have two users, joe and john with emails joe@domain and john@domain. Both of these users share many of the same responsibilities, and trust between the two users is not an issue, so each of them wants to see the other's emails and wants the other to see his. However, each wants to send from their own personal email address.

So basically, emails to joe@domain should be sent to joe's mailbox and john's mailbox. Emails to john@domain should be sent to joe's mailbox and john's mailbox. And emails sent by either user (in outlook, this really isn't the hard part) should be sent from their own personal accounts.

Sharing a single mailbox isn't an option either because both users have different methods or organizing and tracking their emails, so I do want two seperate distinct mailboxes that contain ALL of the emails.

I'm hoping someone can help me out, I'm rather new to the exchange thing, so its possible that I'm missing something simple. In case it matters, we are running SBS 2008, but I'm fully comftorable in exchange mangement console/shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the forwarding option in exchange.

See this guide and start from step 9 http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/MF015.html

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need, just going to make sure I can find it in the server management console...

Comment: I managed to find it, you gave me the right option, but its buried in a slightly different location in the 2008 world (Its on mailbox properties in exchange management console). Thanks though... Sorry for not being able to upvote, I'm usually on stack overflow, so I have no rep here :(

Answer (score 0):

How about a distribution list?  We use a lot of distribution lists setup at work and you can add/remove people from it with relative ease.

Comment: I was initially looking at using distribution lists, the problem was that the email addresses I was using were the personal email addresses for the account. I didn't want joe@domain to be a distribution list because then I would have to change his personal email address to something else... Thanks though